# push notifications received by a limt number of ios devices

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, payload

I have the push notifications service in my application, and I have 600 number of tokens in my database, unfortunately the push notifications are received by just 30 tokens.
I got my iPad token and I put it in the first row in database, I got a push notification, I've tried to test if all tokens are received, so I put it (the same token) in the 35th record, I send push notification, my iPad didn't receive it.
I am working with production push notifications (without sandbox) not development.

```
    $sql="Select apns_devices.pid, apns_devices.appname, apns_devices.appversion, apns_devices.devicetoken, apns_devices.devicemodel, apns_devices.deviceversion, apns_devices.pushbadge, apns_devices.pushalert, apns_devices.pushsound, apns_devices.development, apns_devices.`status`, apns_devices.created, apns_devices.modified, apns_devices.`type`
From apns_devices
Where apns_devices.`status` = 'active'  AND apns_devices.pushalert = 'enabled' AND apns_devices.development = 'production' ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


$payload = '{"aps":{"alert":"'.$message.'","sound":"default","badge":"+1"}}';

$i=0;    
 while ($deviceToken = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) { 
// Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', ''.$deviceToken[3].'') . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
$i++;
        }

echo $i;
```

the echo $i returns 600 which is the number of tokens in database, but not all devices receive the push notifications.

Please help.

Comment: it is resolved now, it was a php script issue

Answer (score 1):

Is it likely that some of the device tokens in your DB are invalid (or at least invalid in the production environment, which would be the case if you have some sandbox device tokens in the DB).

In order to find the invalid tokens you have to use the enhanced binary format (which includes a message ID and expiration time), and Apple will send you error responses for the invalid tokens. In the simple format you are currently using, Apple simply closes the connection when they encounter an invalid token. That's why the messages following that invalid token are not delivered.

Comment: yes right it might there are invalid tokens in DB, please can you send me how can I recognize the invalid tokens? how can I use the feedback service?

Comment: @Fatima Try the code sample [here](http://learn-php-by-example.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/working-with-apple-push-notification.html).

Comment: I tried it, it gave me the invalid tokens which are the development tokens, but still not received by all devices, please tell me if we have another invalid tokens others than development like if some users uninstalled the app, doesn't mean that this device will be invalid? please explain

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close and re-open your socket connection to APNS if $result is false.
The number $i is reporting can be flawed if you don't.

Reminder: Apple closes the socket connection if you try to send a push to a non-valid or expired token.